# Ошибка при поиске в векторе

Tags: c++, строки, vector, find

Есть вектор структур

vector  keywordVec;

```
keywordVec.push_back({ "PROCEDURE", 401 });
keywordVec.push_back({ "BEGIN", 402 });
keywordVec.push_back({ "END", 403 });
```

Нужно осуществить поиск по полю структуры

`string currentTokenName = "END";`

Делаю вот так:

`vector<keywordStruct>::iterator it = find(keywordVec.begin(), keywordVec.end(), currentTokenName);`

Выбивает такую ошибку:

`binaary '==': 'main::keywordStruct' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predifined operator`

Библиотеки, которые подключила

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
```

Как устранить эту ошибку или может есть альтернативные реализации?

Comment: А нельзя было нормально и полноценно оформить минимально рабочий пример?

Comment: Не всегда удобен вектор.   Контейнер нужно выбирать исходя из того, какую задачу решаете.   Если поиск(удаление, добавление) является частой операцией,  то, в данном случаи, лучше подумать о контейнере std::unordered_map(multimap)

Answer (score 1):

```
struct keywordStruct
{
    string s;
    int i;

    bool operator==(const string& str) const
    {
        return this->s == str;
    }
};
```

Просто пропишите в вашей структуре оператор сравнения со строкой

Answer (score 1):

Пусть строковое поле структуры называется `str`. Тогда примерно так:

```
auto it = find(keywordVec.begin(), keywordVec.end(), 
               [currentTokenName](auto v){ return v==currentTokenName; });
```